# How to save shortcode output into database?

Tags: database, wordpress, shortcode

I've got a shortcode to display a text.

[Please check here the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoDiz.png)

When I add this shortcode into my post

[myshortcode langue='EN']

It return the following text : "This is in English" , it works fine when I preview my post

The problem is that it will appear in database into post_content of the posts table, like this : [myshortcode langue='EN']

[Here please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyH8L.png)

How can I do to save in my database the output text : "This is in English" instead of the shortcode [myshortcode langue='EN'] ?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code. Pictures of code are difficult for some device to display and cause accessibilty issues as most screen readers can't read pictures.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and how Wordpress handles shortcodes. When you edit the post it will show the shortcode and not the output generated from PHP for the shortcode.

It's hard to understand why you would want to do what you are trying to do. Possibly you would be better to look at saving the language as custom post meta for the post.

Here is a good writeup on custom post meta : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/